# input is a plain text file where i have to convert into text file with comma or delimiter

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a text file having the following content:

```
===Start Page: 1===
Mr Kumar
 
16 1 483 404 
Saidabad,Saidabad

Hyderabad 500059

Andhra Pradesh

Landmark :Near Matrushri Engineering College
UNTO VR ANT TAN


Bill date 03-Aug-2018
Bill period 02-Jul-2018 to 01-Aug-2018
Pay by date 21-Aug-2018
 
===End Page: 1===


===Start Page: 2===
===End Page: 2===


===Start Page: 3===
S.no Date Time Number Duration/ Pulse Amount
volume

1.SMS - National Messages


S.no Date Time Operator Number Duration Pulse Amount

/ volume

1.National roaming

1.asms

1 14/JUL/2018 09:37:34 Airtel-Chennai 94494 1 1 0.38

2 14/JUL/2018 09:37:39 Airtel-Chennai 9494 1 1 0.38

3 15/JUL/2018 17:16:03 Airtel-Chennai 9702 1 1 0.38

4 15/JUL/2018 17:37:13 Airtel-Chennai 9106 1 1 0.38

5 16/JUL/2018 08:17:41 Airtel-Chennai 9106 1 1 0.38

6 17/JUL/2018 00:09:27 Airtel-Chennai 9106 1 1 0.38

7 17/JUL/2018 00:10:53 Airtel-Chennai 9602 1 1 0.38

8 17/JUL/2018 00:15:40 Airtel-Chennai 9602 1 1 0.38

9 17/JUL/2018 15:02:23 Airtel-Chennai 9494 1 1 0.38

10 23/JUL/2018 16:52:37 Airtel-Chennai 9494 1 1 0.38

11 24/JUL/2018 12:54:16 Airtel-Chennai 9461 1 1 0.38

12 30/JUL/2018 13:44:38 Airtel-Chennai 9494 1 1 0.38

total 12 12 4.56
```

- how can I remove the `===End Page: X===` and `===Start Page: X===`
- how can I keep comma between word to word `14/JUL/2018,09:37:34,Airtel-Chennai,94494,1,1, 0.38` and first 4 lines should be shown as a header.
- how can I write it using apache spark.

Comment: did you try anything so far? I mean, you should at least be able to load the textfile and save it back to disk. Where is the code you're using so far? And did you read about filters? also, I don't get your format, there is no structure except for start and end of a page, so what you be the column header?

Comment: you can try a custom input format for your pages, but even then you're mostly lost as I don't see any structure